# How to use the Stuff function twice in a select in sql

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

How to use the Stuff function twice in a select in sql

Table is:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| Id | col_name|value      |
+----+---------+-----------+   
| 1  | name    |  mar      |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 1  | family  |  ah       |
+----+---------+-----------+ 
| 1  | phone   |  336      |
+----+---------+-----------+ 
| 1  | ID      |  1001     |
+----+---------+-----------+ 
| 1  | email   |  m.h@g.com|
+----+---------+-----------+ 
Required output:
+----+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| Id |     COL_NAME              |         Values            | 
+----+---------------------------+---------------------------+ 
|  1 | Name,Family,Phone,ID,Email|  mar,ah,336,1001,m.h@g.com|
+----+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

In the output of two columns, the  Values must be arranged to be COL_NAME

Comment: Lots of concats (plus coalesce)?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the mentioning of the `stuff()` function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unfortunately, STUFF has a long history of being mistaken for an aggregate concatenation function from another DBMS.  I am changing the tags back until the OP confirms the DBMS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Looks like this comes from posts on MySQL blogs/forum demonstrating how to duplicate `group_concat` on SQL Server with `STUFF(..)` and `For XML`.  Apparently a lot of readers thought the magic was in the STUFF function ...

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this do what you want?

```
select id, 'Name,Family,Phone' as col_name,
       concat(Name, ',', Family, ', ', Phone) as values
from t;
```

(Note:  `values` is a SQL keyword so it is a bad name for a column alias.)